# How to store a response json body to local storage in k6 load test scripts?

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing, k6

Want to use response body item in different post issue in my script. Is there any way holding response body item anywhere and getting that item in another post issue? Searched for k6 load test scripts but didn't find anything.Searching for alternative ways

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. Access the response of a request with `response.body`, store it in a variable and then use this variable's value later? Or do you want to write the responses to disk and use them in a different process? Can you add a rough outline, perhaps with dummy code or comments, of your script(s) and expected/intended behavior?

Answer (score 1):

k6's biggest strength is it's scriptable, you can use js.

To show an example, I'm using [reqres](https://reqres.in/).

```js
import http from 'k6/http';

export default function(){
    let response = http.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1");

    let users = response.json("data")

    // List users
    for (let user of users){
        console.log(`${user.id}\t${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}`)
    }

    // Do some dummy PATCH operations, change their first_name to firstie
    for (let user of users){
        const response = http.patch(`https://reqres.in/api/users/${user.id}/`, JSON.stringify(
            {
                first_name: "firstie"
            }
        ));

        console.log(`User ${user.id} status code: ${response.status}`)
    }

}
```